# UIPopovercontroller not detecting touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController which is initialised with a custom view controller - photoBoothController.

photoBoothController contains a UIView called canvas. This canvas contains several gestureRecognizers which detect gestures and perform appropriate functions.

The problem is that the gestureRecognizers are not being recognised when the UIPopoverController is displayed. I've tested this by adding a UIButton. If I add it as a subview of the photoBoothController, I can press it. However if I add it as a subview of the canvas I can no longer press it.

So my question is how can I pass the gestures to the canvas? I've tried adding `[canvas becomeFirstResponder]` in the viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear methods of the photoBoothController but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I know the code is otherwise sound, as it works perfectly when run as a regular view and not in a UIPopoverController.

Many thanks.

Code in photoBoothController:

```
#import "PhotoBoothController.h"


@implementation PhotoBoothController

@synthesize canvas;
@synthesize photoImage;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

-(void)showOverlayWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  if (![_marque actionForKey:@"linePhase"]) {
    CABasicAnimation *dashAnimation;
    dashAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"lineDashPhase"];
    [dashAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f]];
    [dashAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
    [dashAnimation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [_marque addAnimation:dashAnimation forKey:@"linePhase"];
  }

  _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
  _marque.position = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + canvas.frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + canvas.frame.origin.y);

  CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, frame);
  [_marque setPath:path];
  CGPathRelease(path);

  _marque.hidden = NO;

}

-(void)scale:(id)sender {

    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      _lastScale = 1.0;
    }

    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = photoImage.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [photoImage setTransform:newTransform];

    _lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
    [self showOverlayWithFrame:photoImage.frame];
}

-(void)rotate:(id)sender {

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

      _lastRotation = 0.0;
      return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (_lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = photoImage.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [photoImage setTransform:newTransform];

    _lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
    [self showOverlayWithFrame:photoImage.frame];
}


-(void)move:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"MOVING GESTURE");

  CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:canvas];

  if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _firstX = [photoImage center].x;
    _firstY = [photoImage center].y;
  }

  translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);

  [photoImage setCenter:translatedPoint];
  [self showOverlayWithFrame:photoImage.frame];
}

-(void)tapped:(id)sender {
  _marque.hidden = YES;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if (!_marque) {
    _marque = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    _marque.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _marque.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    _marque.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    _marque.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    _marque.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
    _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
    _marque.position = CGPointMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x + canvas.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y + canvas.frame.origin.y);
  }
  [[self.view layer] addSublayer:_marque];

  UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
  [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

  UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
  [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
  [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [canvas addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
  [tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [tapProfileImageRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [canvas addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.canvas becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [self setPhotoImage:nil];
  [self setCanvas:nil];
  [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark UIGestureRegognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]];
}

@end
```

Code to initialise:

```
- (void)presentPhotoBoothForPhoto:(UIImage *)photo button:(UIButton *)button {

    //Create frame outline image
    UIImage *outline = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"HumptyLine1Frame.png"] adjustForResolution];
    UIImageView *outlineView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:outline];
    outlineView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, outline.size.width, outline.size.height);

    //Create photo image. Already ajusted to resolution?
    UIImageView *photoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photo];
    photoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, photo.size.width, photo.size.height);

    //Add done button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(renderPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Create canvas with outline as the frame into which the image is rendered
    //Here is where I'll need to define a custom method to create a frame shaped by the outline
    UIView *canvas = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:outlineView.frame];
    [canvas setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [canvas addSubview:photoView];
    [canvas addSubview:doneButton];

    //Create a photoBooth and set its contents
    PhotoBoothController *photoBoothController = [[PhotoBoothController alloc] init];
    //resize the view
    photoBoothController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(canvas.frame.size.width+100, canvas.frame.size.height+50);
    photoBoothController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    photoBoothController.canvas = canvas;
    photoBoothController.photoImage = photoView;
    [photoBoothController.view addSubview:canvas];
    //photoBoothController.view.gestureRecognizers = canvas.gestureRecognizers;

    self.photoBooth = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:photoBoothController];
    [self.photoBooth presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
[photoBoothController.view addSubview:canvas];
[photoBoothController.view addSubview:outlineView];
```

you are adding outlineView over the canvasView and both are had the same frame .. try this

```
[photoBoothController.view  bringSubviewToFront:canvas];
```

**Just An Example :**

```
TestVC *test = [[TestVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestVC" bundle:nil];

UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

test.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(testView.frame.size.width+100, testView.frame.size.height+50);

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(sss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[testView addSubview:button];

[test.view addSubview:testView];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:test];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made a difference, except that the frame is now behind the picture. Still doesn't repsond to any touches and the UIButton only works if it's a subview of photoBoothController and not canvas... Somehow I need to pass the touches from photoBoothController to the canvas as it seems to be blocking them?

Comment: ok try to do that at separated levels .. add the button to canvas and the canvas to photoBoothController.view and don't add anything else and check if it works.

Comment: Ok tried that, but the button still doesn't work. Only if it's added as a subview of the photoBoothController directly... Should I be passing on the gestures somehow? Only my photoBoothController conforms to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate...

Comment: can you change the background color for the canvas to check that the button is completely inside the canvas view ?

Comment: Ahah! Yes, the button was outside the bounds of the canvas, good thinking. And moving it within the bounds made it respond. However, the gestures still aren't recognized when I add an image. I should be able to pan, rotate etc and it stays static still...

Comment: because you are adding the gestures to the view not to the imageView :)

Comment: Well the imageView is an instance variable of the class. So when the gesture in the view is recognised, it makes the appropriate adjustments to the instance of the imageview. But the gestures are never recognised as their methods are never called. But it works fine if not being loaded into a uipopovercontroller...

Comment: I've added all the code in case that helps... The button works fine as per your example, but its the gestures that aren't recognised now...

Comment: try to remove the `[canvas becomefirsResponder];`

Comment: Didn't make a difference unfortunately... If I load it as a modal view that I set up in storyboard it works fine. Maybe I'll just have to go that way and not do it as a popover :(

Comment: ok since you create another question for this issue I think that I deserve to have this answer accepted .. right :) ?

Comment: This was actually the second question I added since the first one was being ignored. I'll give you the answer if I don't get any others in the next couple of days - want to leave it open in case someone else comes up with a solution, since I haven't actually fixed it yet. But I really appreciate the time and help!